# Get elements with an id in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to get all the *input* tags with an *id*.
Right now, my code is:

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].id) { .. }
}
```

I'd like something cleaner if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look for the existence of an attribute with `[attribute name]`:

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id]');
```

[See the W3C docs on attribute presence selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation).

Comment: On the off-chance, the OP doesn't know, we should probably point out that this is a relatively new method that won't work in a lot of older browsers or IE up to 8 AFAIK.

Comment: @Erik Yes, I had presumed the OP was aware of that, but it's a good point to emphasise.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[id]');
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Something like this?</del>

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
  i,
  l = inputs.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
  if (inputs[i].hasAttribute('id'))
  {
    //do some code
  }
}
```

Edit to add:
Oops, turns out `hasAttribute` isn't as cross-browser as I thought...

### "cleanest" code steps:

1. use jQuery
2. `$('input[id]')`
3. profit

Comment: This would work, but I don't think it meets the qualification of *something cleaner*. But I guess that's subjective. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw, good point, i went for "something cross-browser".

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that at first when I saw your answer, but I double checked and `hasAttribute` isn't cross browser either. [IE support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t115) for it starts in the same browser where `qsa` starts (IE8).

Comment: @patrick dw, d'oh! I thought hasAttribute had been around longer than IE8. I'ma update my answer...

Answer (score -1):

use

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id]');
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for.

Comment: @patrick dw: After reading question again I realize you are right my apology :)